# regex to not match new line

Tags: regex, emacs

The below regex should match only the lines that does not start with # character followed by anything.

```
^[^#].*
```

But if the buffer contains a empty line before it it matches the next line even if it starts with #.

For the following input it fails

```
This line is matched as expected

# this line should not be matched, but it does if the above line is empty !?
```

Comment: Note, that the summary of your question is misleading. From the emacs manual (about regular expressions): `.' (Period) is a special character that matches any single character **except a newline**. The answer of Sniffer tells you what the real problem is.

Comment: Note also, that if you want to skip comments in a source code file there are other means. Especially, `(eq (syntax-ppss-context (syntax-ppss)) 'comment)` is your friend for such cases. If this form evaluates to true you can skip the search result (i.e., continue search without exploiting the found match).

Comment: Note also, that the regular expression `^[^#].*` can be dangerous. If you have very long lines in the text file that can cause an overflow inside the regexp-engine. Furthermore, it can significantly slow down the search. It is better to look for the next line not starting with `?#` and then search for the regular expression you really are looking for (avoiding `.*`) limiting the search to the end of line.

Comment: @user2708138 Really nice summary of ideas. I really liked what you said about long lines and you are correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can fix it like this:

```
^[^#\r\n].*
```

The problem with your original expression `^[^#].*` is that `[^#]` was matching the newline character *(the empty line)*, thus allowing the dot `.` to match the entire line after the empty one, so the dot isn't actually matching the newline, the `[^#]` is the one doing it.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wM3vB7)

Comment: Nearly all of the regular expressions that I write, I want to match a single line.  Is there a simple way to limit `[^bar]*` to only match a single line?  `[^\r\nbar]*` clutters up the RE (an RE tend to be cryptic anyway).  I'm hoping for something like `(let ((single-line-re t)) (search-forward-regex ...))`, but I expect I'll just need to start writing `[^\r\n` where I now write `[^`

Comment: Your welcome but I suggest you post this as a normal question and I am sure someone will help you.